# "You'll be in for it." - meaning of using "it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

The Cambridge Dictionary's article ["be in for sth"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-in-for-sth) gives two examples:

> The weather forecast says we're in for heavy rain this evening.
>   You'll be in for **it** (= you'll be in trouble) if you don't do what she tells you.

The first example is clear: the object to "to be in for sth" is "heavy rain".

But the second one appears a bit enigmatic to me.
Does "**it**" refer to any part of the sentence or context?
Or is "to be in for it" just a fixed expression for "to be/get in trouble"?

Comment: A dread consequence (typically punishment).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***In for it*** is a fixed expression, meaning retribution or punishment will follow. From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20for%20it):

> **[in for it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20for%20it)**
>
> informal
>
> certain to be punished
>
> *If his parents find out what he's done, he'll be in for it.*

Comment: Which is to say, the "it" in this sentence is a pronoun to stand in for whatever trouble is expected.

Comment: I agree, referring to past or current actions someone did.

Comment: it => consequences of some action that (triggered) the consequences. Makes sense?

Comment: A variant is "now you're really *gonna get it*".

Comment: Is this is inferred from the context? Can it mean otherwise in some situations?

Comment: @Alvaro I suppose one could say “yes, we’re really in for it” if someone points out a bad weather forecast (e.g. in response to them saying “we’re expecting thunderstorms tonight”).

Comment: Sure, figuratively, punished with inclement weather.